# virtualenvwrapper-win hangs at "Installing setuptools, pip, wheel..."

Tags: windows-10, virtualenv, python-3.7, virtualenvwrapper

I was setting up virtualenvwrapper-win and was trying to create a virtual environment using, `mkvirtualenv py3env1` and the process hangs at `Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...`
At Keyboard interrupt it shows some errors.

I have tried to install as below 
`virtualenv venv --no-wheel`
it hangs in the same place

```
C:\virtualenvs>mkvirtualenv pytorch1
Using base prefix 'c:\\python37'
New python executable in C:\virtualenvs\pytorch1\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python37\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 834, in main
    symlink=options.symlink,
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1129, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs, download=download)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 976, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel_with_search_dir(download, project_names, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1066, in _install_wheel_with_search_dir
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=script)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 901, in call_subprocess
    line = stdout.readline()
KeyboardInterrupt
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? Y
```

Comment: Having same issue.. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Not yet, Could it be a Windows issue?

Comment: Use same command with `-v` flag and post the verbose output please..

Comment: The verbose out put of mkvirtualenv is here, https://gist.github.com/christy1/3603b4a4221bb21ccb1251c0e7ef8aa8

Comment: Have you tried this: `py -m venv [a path you desire]`  ?   And then enter in the path: `cd [path]`   and then `activate`   After this in `Scripts` was creater the archives

Comment: I am trying to do this in virtualenvwrapper.